# Azure VM: Adding a Reserved IP address to an existing VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

What I have read so far on the web is that there is no way to add a reserved IP to an existing VM (unless I recreate the VM which I am trying to avoid). However, I have noticed that external IP of my VM and the cloud service is same.

1. [Reserved IP Addresses](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/) page explains how to "To use a Reserved IP with Cloud Services". I have looked everywhere in the Azure Management Portal but couldn't find a configuration setting for Service Configuration Schema.
2. I am using the Azure scheduler to turn-off the VMs at night and on the weekends. From the following I understand is that there is something that I need to write in the scheduler script to re-assign the Reserved IP when the VM starts in the morning. Did I get it right?

   > Shutdown VM - Previously, when all the Virtual Machine instances in a
   >   cloud service were moved to the Shutdown state (stop/deallocated), the
   >   public IP would be released and a new public IP would be assigned when
   >   one of the Virtual Machines instances was started. However, with this
   >   release, if the VM uses a Reserved IP, then the Reserved IP can be
   >   used when re-deploying the VMs.

P.S. Is Stack Overflow the best place to ask this sort of questions relating to Azure or shall I use Server Fault in the future? I have seen Azure questions in both websites.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At Build 2015 they announced this is now possible and VERY easy.
Simply open Azure powershell and run this:

```
New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "ipname" -Location "West US" -ServiceName "somevm"
```

If you run this it will reserve an IP named "ipname" and associate it with the already deployed instance "somevm.cloudapp.net"

Comment: Thanks. However I believe this reserved IP is for internal purpose only. It is not at the service level. Hence if I want to refer to the VM from outside I can't use the same IP.

Comment: @java_enthu not sure what you are talking about but this definitely sets the VIP which is accessible by anyone in the world

Comment: I tried this. my scenario is bit different. I've posted it here/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678558/reservedips-for-azure-vms-in-a-single-vnet-subnet/32678799?noredirect=1#comment53211642_32678799

Answer (score 9):

In order to assign existing reserved IP to an existing VM, you can use the following command:

```
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP -ServiceName TestService
```

Answer (score 3):

Step by step to create Reserved IP  and using it on Azure VM. Here you can go

[Reserved IP Creation](http://prmdbaora.blogspot.in/2015/06/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none.html)

I have done the Elastic IP Automatic scheduling on AWS.Here is the reference link [Elastic IP Automation on AWS script](http://prmdbaora.blogspot.in/2015_04_01_archive.html).

Between needs to check about How can I write a script for automating the reserved IP for Azure.If you had done it earlier, Kindly share the script this will be very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, we don't support the capability to associate a Reserved IP to an already existing VM. 
We are currently working on the capability to reserve the IP of an existing VM.

Ref: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses/
http://www.petri.com/how-to-reserve-public-virtual-ip-addresses-in-microsoft-azure.htm

Girish Prajwal

Comment: Hi, is this still the case?

Answer (score 0):

For new VMs (with resource manager) you should do the following:

Create new static IP address:

```
$ip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name "<ip-name>"  -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Location eastus -AllocationMethod Static
```

Get information about VM Network Interface:

```
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Name <vm-name> | Select -ExpandProperty NetworkProfile
```

Get corresponding network interface and set new ip and update NIC:

```
$netInt = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName "group-name" -Name <nic-name>
$netInt.IpConfigurations[0].PublicIpAddress = $ip
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $netInt
```

Answer (score 0):

I read all of the previous entries and did not come away with a clear picture of how to proceed with assigning a reserved IP address to my existing Azure classic VM, so I opened a support ticket.  I got excellent clear guidance from "Sruthi Saranya K", a support engineer in Azure Networking.  Sruthi stated "in classic deployment model it is not possible to have a static public IP assigned to a VM", which I had read elsewhere, but she clarified that you simply assign the IP address to the cloud service and not the VM directly, then the VM will automatically pick up on the change.  I outline all of the commands here for your convenience, starting from an Azure PowerShell prompt.  The critical command was specified in the top response here, but not all of the steps.  Also, that example also includes specifying the service, but it does not appear to be a supported parameter for that command, instead there is a second command to associate the IP with the service.

add-azureaccount  (to log in to Azure from PowerShell)
New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "ipname" -Location "East US"
get-azurereservedip (just to see what the reserved IP address is)
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName "ipname" -ServiceName "your cloud service name"

Also, depending on the use, you may want to look up the IP address on mxtoolbox.com to make sure it is not already blacklisted.  My reserved IP was for a web site, but the default @ DNS entry for the domain meant our domain was generally going to be associated with that IP address, and previously our mail has been blacklisted because our web server IP address was sullied by some other Azure tenant.  If you get a blacklisted address, you can remove it and get a new one, also a suggestion from Sruthi.  Here are the commands to remove the reserved IP, and to remove the cloud service association if needed:

remove-azurereservedip
Remove-AzureReservedIPAssociation

My sincere thanks to Sruthi for making it so simple and preventing an unnecessary redeployment of our company's public web server.

Answer (score 0):

Add Public IP to an Existing VM

1. Log into the portal
2. Find the Resource Group (RG) where your VM is Located
3. Confirm your VM has a network interface - if not, create one (it should have one)
4. Create a Public IP Address (static or dynamic, doesn't matter) by adding one to your RG from the marketplace (do this first so it is creating while you make your NSG).
5. Create a Network Service Group by adding one to your RG from the marketplace and associating it with your VM.
6. Once the NSG has deployed, go back to the Overview of your PIP and click the "Associate" button in the info section of the blade.
7. Select the Network Interface of your VM you validated in step 3.
   Get a cup of coffee or something, it will be a minute, but otherwise you're done.

Answer (score -1):

```
New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "nameIP" -Location "East US" -ServiceName "azureA2vm"
```

Get this:

```
New-AzureReservedIP : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ServiceName'.
At line:1 char:70
+ New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "nameIP" -Location "East US" -ServiceNam ...
+                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzureReservedIP], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.NewAzureReservedIPCmdlet
```

Check PowerShell version. Update to latest version.

Comment: Be sure to update Powershell. If the PowerShell is outdated the commands will not work. After updating the powershell one is able to assign reserved IP to an existing VM.