# ReservedIPs for Azure VMs in a single VNet/subnet

Tags: linux, azure, networking, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I've 8 VMs (linux based) running a single VNet on Azure. If I've two VMs running a service on the same port which shows me machine status or shows some common details which is specific to the VM. Say for example

VM-1 runs a service on 8080 port and same same service has been deployed on VM-2 which runs on the same port 8080.  To access to a service running on port 8080 I am opening a port on VM-1 through end points. I am able to access 8080 from web browser through VM-1 using servicename.webapp.net:8080. But If I want to check the status of VM-2, I am not able to open the port 8080 on the VM-2.  Probably because the port is opened at the service level and not the VM level. Is there a way I can open the port at the VM level and use VM-x:port?

Another approach I thought which could be useful is : Assign the staticIP/ReservedIP to each of the VM and open the port on individual machines should be possible, instead of open the port at the VNet/service level.  Is it possible to assign static/reserved IP to all 8 of the machines once they have been started and operational? And we also need to make sure that, after restart all the eight machines retain the same IPs.

I tried following blog https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/ and tried following command :

```
$image = Get-AzureVMImage|?{$_.ImageName -like "*AMI-20150919-849187*"} 
New-AzureVMConfig -Name StaticIPVMCOnfig -InstanceSize Small -ImageName $image.ImageName 
-CurrentStorageAccountName "myStorageACName" 
| Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux -LinuxUser root -Password MyP@ssword! 
| New-AzureVM -ServiceName myCloudServiceName -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP 
-Location "West Europe"
```

I still see the new VM is getting launched with same same VIP as the other VMs in the VNet. I am not sure if I am missing something.

Attaching the screenshots one is created without static/reservedIP CMDlets. Another is created from PowerShell. Both share the same VIP.

[image: This VM is created before without powershell or reservedIPs]

[image: This VM is created with Powershell.]
Could someone please help with this?

PS: Intentionally I am keeping the public VIPs to show that they are same. (I've closed and not using this service anymore).

Thanks,
JE

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can assign static IP to to the VMs using powershell command-

```
get-azurevm -servicename "testservice" -name "testvm" | Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress "10.87.96.41" | Update-AzureVM
```

Next thing is you want to make sure you don't lose the IP when instance goes to stopped state. For this what you can do is define explicit parameter `StayProvisioned` with the stop azure vm command in powershell-

```
stop-azurevm -ServiceName "testservice" -Name "testvm" -StayProvisioned
```

StayProvisioned doesn't allow IP to be freed even if VM is stopped.

If you are looking for public IP of VM-

"Every Virtual Machine is automatically assigned a free public Virtual IP (VIP) address"

In order to find out the public ip goto- Azure portal and then your VM dashboard. Here at the right side you see a quick glance tab under which you will be able to see the public IP. Snapshot for your reference-

[image]

You can use this public ip to directly connect to vm using RDP. Using powershell you can use below command for the same.

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "testservice" -Name "testvm" | select PublicIPAddress
```

**NOTE** - Public IP will be null if instance is in stopped state. To know more on public IP you can read this-

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/

[Edited]

Comment: Thanks. I believe this fixes the IP inside the service hence all the IPs inside a services have static IPs. But still you can't access this VM from a browser using IP. I am looking for something which assigns the fixed public IP to a VM.

Comment: This assigns fixed private ip to vm. You can rdp using this ip.

Comment: However if you want to use reserved IP to your existing vm then this link will surely help you-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454255/azure-vm-adding-a-reserved-ip-address-to-an-existing-vm

Comment: Well I tried this Aatif, it helps when I have one VM instead of 8 vms in the same VNet.

Comment: The link you shared I visited it previously thanks :)

Comment: Hai Aatif, this will definitely work if the cloud service has only one VM. In the case of multiple VMs in a single cloud service it's not working.

Comment: Azure Doc. says: "Every Virtual Machine is automatically assigned a free public Virtual IP (VIP) address"

Comment: I did go through the document : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/ Also tried following the command given there : $image = Get-AzureVMImage|?{$_.ImageName -like "*AMI-20150919-849187*"} 
New-AzureVMConfig -Name StaticIPVMCOnfig -InstanceSize Small -ImageName $image.ImageName 
-CurrentStorageAccountName "myStorageACName" 
| Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux -LinuxUser root -Password MyP@ssword! 
| New-AzureVM -ServiceName myCloudServiceName -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP 
-Location "West Europe"

Comment: This brings up a new VM from the image but, the VIP what I see is the same as other VMs. :) So, still I am not able to use it VM:port.

Comment: Well I got a useful link for you. You can add a public IP on VM level-  http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/10/28/step-by-step-assign-a-public-ip-to-a-vm-in-azure.aspx
However new IP will be picked once you shut down and restart the VM, as Azure public IP is dynamic.